# Reversing colormaps or specifying colors in a matplotlib/pandas plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, scipy

I am following some examples from the book [Python for Data Analysis](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do), and came across an interesting problem. I was wondering if there is a way to "reverse" of a colormap, for example from a blue extreme to a pink extreme to the opposite (pink to blue) for the 'cool' color map.

[SciPy.org colormaps](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps)

In the example below, I chart baby names using the 'cool' color map, that shows girls in blue color and boy in pink color. Is there a way to 'reverse' the mapping?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not well documented in the link you showed, but each colormap has a corresponding reversed colormap that you can access by appending an `"_r"` to the colormap name.  In your case, the colormap name would be `"cool_r"`.

This fact is hinted at in the code samples (look for the `.endswith("_r")` portions of the code), but it isn't really stated very succinctly.

Comment: @mglison Great answer! btw, a simpler problem..how could I specify, for example, red for "F" and "yellow for "M"? Don't know how to specify the two components of the df.

Comment: @LuisMiguel -- I'm not sure that I understand your question.  Are you asking about constructing a new colormap?  Or are you asking about something specific to your pandas dataframe?  I suppose either way, I probably can't help you ... I've never really spent much time using either ;-).  You could post a follow up question if you don't find an answer after googleing a bit.

Comment: @mglison Thank you again. Yes, the question is more about manipulating DataFrames for plotting. I'll do more research or post here in a separate Q if I can't find the answer. Btw, congrats on your top ranking here! Amazing.